# sudo apt-get upgrade error

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources

upgrading the Ubuntu this error occurs:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
error Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type) E: The list of sources could not be read
```

Line 1 in source list is this:

```
123#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the line from:

```
123#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted
```

To:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted
```